# Android How can I detect autofill pressed?

Tags: android, kotlin, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I use AutofillManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/autofill/AutofillManager and can't understand how can I detect is user enter value himself or user select any autofill option.
I try to use `editText.autofillValue` but it contains value both cases

Anyone knows how can I resolve it? Help me, please!)

P.S. code

I have function to request autofill

```
fun allowAutoFill(view: View?) {
        if (view != null) {
            val afm = requireContext().getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)
            if (afm.isAutofillSupported && afm.isEnabled) {
                afm?.requestAutofill(view)
            }
        }
    }
```

After that i want to know user enter something or select value from autofill. It's needed for analytics.

```
private fun isAutoFillApplied() = binding?.editPassword?.autofillValue?.textValue?.isNotEmpty() == true
```

but `binding?.editPassword?.autofillValue` contains value if user enter something and if user select autofill option

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: @ahmadbajwa I have function to request autofill


`fun allowAutoFill(view: View?) {
        if (view != null) {
            val afm = requireContext().getSystemService(AutofillManager::class.java)
            if (afm.isAutofillSupported && afm.isEnabled) {
                afm?.requestAutofill(view)
            }
        }
    }
`
After that i want to detect user enter something or select value from autofill. It's needed for analytics.


```private fun isAutoFillApplied() = binding?.editPassword?.autofillValue?.textValue?.isNotEmpty() == true```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find cool answer, so I used bad dirty hack.
I have two edittext in screen. If user select any autofill option this edittexts filled the same time. So if time difference on text changed not so big, I fill `isAutofill` value as `true`.
This is really not pretty solution, but I can't find another.

This is looks like this

```
var lastChangedTime = 0L
var isAutoFill = false
var lastRepeatPassword: String? = null

editPassword.addTextChangedListener { text ->
                lastChangedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

editRepeatPassword.addTextChangedListener { text ->
               if (text.toString() != lastRepeatPassword) {
                   lastRepeatPassword = text.toString()
                   isAutoFill = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastChangedTime) < 50
               }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

I honestly have no idea why developers still request people to repeat a password twice in 2023. I never typed in a password in the last 5 years. But that's besides the point.

AutofillNode has a param called [onFill](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/autofill/AutofillNode#onFill()). Use that instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).